# Some questions in set theory about belonging

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Some questions about set theory:

1.If $a$ is an element of a set $A$, is it a subset of $A$ or not?

2.If not, can $A$ be a subset of $a$ ?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is. (well, technically, it forms the subset {a} of A). 2. See 1.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  An element is not normally a subset.

Comment: It could be a subset of $A$, but in most cases is not. However, $\{a\}$ (the set whose only element is $a$) always is a subset of $A$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas any example?

Comment: There is an answer already that has a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It may or may not be. For instance, $A=\{\emptyset\}$ is a set with a single element $a=\emptyset$. In this case it is also the case that $a\subseteq A$, namely $\emptyset \subseteq A$, simply because $\emptyset \subseteq B$ for any set $B$. However, $A=\{1\}$ is also a set with a single element, namely $a=1$. In this case $a\nsubseteq A$, simply becuase $a$ is not even a set so one can't speak of it being a subset (emphasis here on *set*) of anything.

2) If $a\in A$, then if $A\subseteq a$ then any element of $A$ in an element of $a$. In particular, $a$ must be a set and, since $a\in A$ it follows that $a\in a$. We now get into the question of which axioms you choose for set theory. Many axiomatizations disallow $a\in a$, but some, called non-well-founded sets, may allow it. So, the answer is, naively this is not allowed, but the notion of such sets is studied.

Comment: what about ZFC?

Comment: Such sets are now allowed then.

Comment: any example? I have no idea

Comment: example of what?

Comment: the second question

Comment: I suggest you read about non-well-founded sets.

Answer (score 1):

Example: $$A=\{3,\{4\},5,\{5\}\}$$  $3$ is an element, but not a subset, of $A$. $\{3\}$ is a subset, but not an element, of $A$.  $4$ is neither an element nor a subset of $A$, but $\{4\}$ is an element, but not a subset, of $A$.  $5$ is an element, but not a subset, of $A$.  $\{5\}$ is both an element and a subset of $A$.

For the second question, the answer is "maybe".  The [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), which is part of the widely used Zermelo-Frankel axioms, prohibits $A$ to be an element of itself, which I believe excludes this possibility.  The short answer is that no familiar sets will admit this property.

Comment: Sorry here I mean for the same $a$,not $\{a\}$